# Unable to connect to Database Engine after trying to move tempdb

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I've just made a boo-boo in my personal SQL instance. I wanted to move tempdb files to C:\tempdb.mdf and C:\templog.ldf respectively. The alter database ...modify file... command ran successfully. However, what I didn't realise was that I cannot create a file in C:\ , only folders can be created there. So after running the modify file command and restarting the service, the new files were not created i.e. C:\tempdb.mdf and C:\templog.ldf.

When I tried to get properties of the tempdb database to see where the files were pointing to, I found I could not get the properties nor any longer connect to the database instance. So eventhough I can restart the services in Config Manager, I am unable to connect to the instance either using SSMS or SQLCMD. I get the error that the file cannot be found.

Apart from re-installing the instance (as I don't have a backup of the master database), is there any other way I can fix this issue please?

Thank  you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to startup the SQL Server instance in minimal configuration mode and connect to it via the command prompt with SQLCMD, as discussed in this article: [How to Start SQL Server if You Lost TEMPDB Data files](https://www.xtivia.com/blog/start-sql-server-lost-tempdb-data-files/). Note this will put the server in single user mode.

After you connect to it, you should be able to execute `ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE` and modify the file locations to an appropriate location. Then shutdown and restart the instance.

Steps from the aforementioned article for reference:

> 1. Open command prompt window #1 as ADMIN and go to the BINN directory where SQL Server is installed.

> 2. Then execute command `Sqlservr.exe /f /c`

> 3. Then open one more command window #2 and if this is a default instance then open SQLCMD  using the following command `SQLCMD –S localhost –E`

> 4. Execute the ALTER DATABASE command: `USE MASTER GO ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdb, FILENAME = 'C:\NEWPATH\tempdb.mdf') GO`

> 5. Now go back to Command window #1 and hit CTRL C. It will ask if you want to stop the instance. Y/N. Enter Y

> 6. Now start the SQL Server instance from configuration manager. You should see the new data file created and SQL Server started.

Comment: Btw might be best to start backing up `master` (and really all databases in general).